# Is there a way to include linked documents in a table entry of a fragment?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've been challenged to include in a given fragment both the notes of an element and the linked document associated with it (if any). I've developed the following sql query and fragment:

```
select obj2.Name, obj2.stereotype, obj2.note as [notes-Formatted], doc.DocID as linkedDocument from ((t_connector conn inner join t_object obj on (obj.object_id=conn.start_object_id or obj.object_id=conn.end_object_id)) inner join t_object obj2 on (obj2.object_id=conn.start_object_id or obj2.object_id=conn.end_object_id)) inner join t_document doc on (obj2.ea_guid=doc.ElementID) where conn.stereotype = 'something' and obj.object_id = #OBJECTID# and obj2.stereotype = 'block' and doc.DocType = 'ModelDocument'
```

[image]

The notes is fine, but the Linked Document part doesn't seem doable. The best I'm managing to do is getting the documentID.

[image]

However, I need the actual linked document contents.

Any clues? Is it possible?

Comment: Not with an SQL Fragment, but you can use a regular fragment for name, notes and linked document.

Comment: But how do I do that if the element I want the notes and linkedDocs from is one that is connected via stereotyped connector to the element that if coming from the template?

Comment: The easiest way is to use virtual documents and have them point to your specific object. See https://bellekens.com/2015/11/12/tutorial-generate-complex-documents-from-enterprise-architect-with-a-two-step-semi-automated-approach/ for more details

Comment: A Document script fragment might also be an option.

Comment: With the document script how would I call the actuall linked document? what would the xml contain?

Comment: A document script doesn't require an xml. You have to return an rft. Read up on the examples in the manual for the document script.